# How to handle a touch gesture by multiple components in react native?

Tags: react-native

Using React Native 0.47 and yarn, I'm creating an introduction section in which you can swipe through multiple pages and finally get to the home page.
So we swipe pages from right to left and move like this:  *Slide1 -> Slide2 -> Slide3 -> Slide4 -> Home* . I have a component that displays a slide page which covers all of the screen. For example, first slide looks like this:

[image: Slide]

And the code for that is :

```
class IntroSlide extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.introSlide, this.props.myStyle]}>
        <View style={styles.introSlideIconView}>
          <Icon name={this.props.iconName} size={SLIDE_ICON_SIZE} color="white"/> 
        </View>
        <View style={styles.introSlideTextView}>
          <Text style={styles.introSlideTextHeader}> {this.props.headerText} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.introSlideText}> {this.props.text} </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And i use it that here:

```
import AppIntro from 'react-native-app-intro'; 
// Other imports here
export default class Intro extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
        <AppIntro
          showSkipButton={false}
          nextBtnLabel={<Text style={styles.introButton}>بعدی</Text>}
          doneBtnLabel={<Text style={styles.introButton}>شروع</Text>}
        >

          <IntroSlide 
            iconName="user" 
            myStyle={styles.introSlide1}
            headerText="DontCare"
            text= "SomeTextDoesntMatter"
          />       
         </AppIntro>
       </View>
        );

      }
    }
```

I'm using [react-native-app-intro](https://github.com/FuYaoDe/react-native-app-intro) for this which provides me a very cool swiper but here's the problem:

I have a small `View` component with an `Icon` ([react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)) in it as you can see that i want to rotate as i swipe to the next page. I created a panResponder in `IntroSlide` and set it to top `View` of it. but my slide can't receive any events. i think some parent views provided by `react-native-app-intro` captures all the events and i can still swipe through pages but no console log appears. here's what i did:

```
class IntroSlide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: () => console.log("Moving"),
    });

    this.pan = panResponder;
  }



 render () {
    return (
      <View 
         style={[styles.introSlide, this.props.myStyle]}
         {...this.pan.panHandlers}
      >
        <View style={styles.introSlideIconView}>
          <Icon name={this.props.iconName} size={SLIDE_ICON_SIZE} color="white"/> 
        </View>
        <View style={styles.introSlideTextView}>
          <Text style={styles.introSlideTextHeader}>   {this.props.headerText} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.introSlideText}> {this.props.text} </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
   }
 }
```

I did the same to the `View` component with `flex: 1` and i had different result. i get console logs as expected but i can't swipe anymore. So how can i swipe through pages while receiving touch events in parent component ? (In other words, i want two different components to receive touch events, and I'm developing for android)

Comment: If you want 2 different views to respond differently to ui gestures then the icon should also be encapsulated inside a component with the same constructor code (create and register panresponder)